# Valid cache path problem with Laravel Lumen into Google App Engine

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, lumen

I deployed a Laravel Lumen app to Google App Engine Standard.

```
runtime: php72

env_variables:
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_DEBUG: false
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ...
```

Calling a api resource does work with google app engine url.

But when I call a url, which gives back html content, it shows me an error:
Please provide a valid cache path

Into my local development environment it creates a file into storage/framework/views
I think into Google App Engine it can't save this cache file.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not write to the APP Engine file system due to the distributed nature of your application. You need to write files to GCS.

[Reading and Writing to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)